# Gitlab-Runner doesn't work with GPU

Tags: linux, windows, gpu, gitlab

I have project, acellerated on GPU. It works on Gitlab CI on linux and windows. 
It works locally, but there is "CM-ERROR: Internal Error" on CI. 
Adding gitlab-runner to video group has helped on linux:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video gitlab-runner
```

I have run gitlab-runner as root on windows. It doesn't work

How to fix it?

Comment: Windows doesn't use Root. Could you please edit your question to make it more clear and specific what you've done.

Comment: @music2myear I solve this problem by using multi runner service:

gitlab-runner run